# Is $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH after source install okay?

Tags: rosinstall

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After I did a source install to /media/apps/ros, as suggested in this [question](http://answers.ros.org/question/3856/ros-electric-desktop-full-not-found), is my $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH, shown below, okay?
lucid@lucid-desktop:~$ echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH
/media/apps/ros/robot_model_tutorials:/media/apps/ros/visualization_tutorials:/media/apps/ros/geometry_tutorials:/media/apps/ros/common_tutorials:/media/apps/ros/ros_tutorials:/media/apps/ros/documentation:/media/apps/ros/geometry_experimental:/media/apps/ros/robot_model_visualization:/media/apps/ros/geometry_visualization:/media/apps/ros/diagnostics_monitors:/media/apps/ros/executive_smach_visualization:/media/apps/ros/visualization:/media/apps/ros/slam_gmapping:/media/apps/ros/navigation:/media/apps/ros/vision_opencv:/media/apps/ros/laser_pipeline:/media/apps/ros/image_pipeline:/media/apps/ros/image_transport_plugins:/media/apps/ros/perception_pcl:/media/apps/ros/image_common:/media/apps/ros/rx:/media/apps/ros/visualization_common:/media/apps/ros/physics_ode:/media/apps/ros/stage:/media/apps/ros/simulator_gazebo:/media/apps/ros/simulator_stage:/media/apps/ros/xacro:/media/apps/ros/executive_smach:/media/apps/ros/robot_model:/media/apps/ros/assimp:/media/apps/ros/pluginlib:/media/apps/ros/orocos_kinematics_dynamics:/media/apps/ros/nodelet_core:/media/apps/ros/geometry:/media/apps/ros/bullet:/media/apps/ros/filters:/media/apps/ros/eigen:/media/apps/ros/driver_common:/media/apps/ros/diagnostics:/media/apps/ros/common:/media/apps/ros/common_msgs:/media/apps/ros/bond_core:/media/apps/ros/common_rosdeps:/media/apps/ros/ros_comm
lucid@lucid-desktop:~$

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12899/is-$ros_package_path-after-source-install-okay?/) by [StrongEnough](https://answers.ros.org/users/1519/strongenough/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-02-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That is the expected outcome, but you installed in a directory owned by root. I would suggest installing in your user home directory. rosinstall auto generates this based on what it installed. If you are going to build packages yourself, be sure to append to the $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH by following the instructions here http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/InstallingandConfiguringROSEnvironment

---

Originally posted by [Kent Williams](https://answers.ros.org/users/1646/kent-williams/) with karma: 91 on 2012-02-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [StrongEnough](https://answers.ros.org/users/1519/strongenough/) on 2012-02-05**:
I think I see, but was hoping for a better installation. I.E. a start would have been to suggest this: rosinstall ~/ros/electric "http://packages.ros.org/cgi-bin/gen_rosinstall.py?rosdistro=electric&variant=desktop-full&overlay=no" but the stacks would not be nested. Yuk. Giving your answer a thumbs-up because I asked the question poorly.

**Comment by [Kent Williams](https://answers.ros.org/users/1646/kent-williams/) on 2012-02-05**:
I believe it is because of the flexibility that rosinstall provides. If a package can be installed via rosinstall, it's installation directory can be outside of the main ros dir and sometimes really should be since it's often used for building dev source. Then it's auto appended to the package path.

**Comment by [StrongEnough](https://answers.ros.org/users/1519/strongenough/) on 2012-02-05**:
/media is owned by root (just like /opt) but apps is owned by user lucid. My Linux partition didn't allow room for ROS so I installed to a different partition as the installation directions suggested is okay. The "expected outcome" is a bit of a mess, don't you think? Why not a similar directory structure as the binary installation?